# CSS Selector for Descendant, how do I select this?

Tags: html, css

This may be a very stupid question, but I've been looking around on the web for a while and whilst I'm using proper syntax, my elements are not being selected in CSS.

I've made a standard sidebar and have it to the right of my screen with flexbox. I'm not looking for anything fancy, but my CSS broke when I renamed it to a class instead of selecting the aside selector, because I intend to use more aside elements and do not want same style on both of them.

Does anyone know how to fix?

```css
.sidebar {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: white;
  align-self: stretch;
  border-left: 0.2em solid purple;
}

.sidebar h1 {
  margin: 1em;
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid purple;
}

.sidebar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar">
  <h1>This is the sidebar.</h1>
  <p>Check out our awesome links!</p>
  <ul>
    <a href="home.html"><li>Nav Item</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Nav Item</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Nav Item</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Nav Item</li></a>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

The .sidebar itself works but .sidebar h1 and .sidebar ul does not.

Comment: https://validator.nu/

Comment: missing a `.` in the second selector

Comment: @TemaniAfif this was a formatting error it is not missing in my css file

Comment: now your code works fine, what's the issue?

Comment: It's not applying the styles on my end

Comment: Try clearing cache. Your code as presented is applying styles to the `h1` and the `ul`. To test, add a background color to the `ul`. https://jsfiddle.net/h0dzspm5/

Comment: Did you use an ID instead of a class before? In this case, the relevance of your CSS selectors changed and .sidebar h1 might now be overwritten by an other CSS rule with a higher "weight" (e.g. a selector with two classes or with an ID).

Comment: You say "my CSS broke", but can you give some more details? Especially since it works fine here... Ehm, you don't have any other elements with class sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it. I had overwritten my styles in a different part of my css file. Thanks everyone for the suggestions.